# Migrate Module: How skip whole item (not value)

Tags: migrations

I have a xml file that creates nodes via migrate.

I need to define the following:

Each job has a field "location". I have written a process plugin to process the value
When the returned value is "null"
... skip the row (not just the field - skip the whole job item)
I thought I do it right by using this yml structure / script

```
process:

  _job_location:
    - plugin: process_job_location
      source: src_job_location
    - plugin: log

  field_job_location_ref:
    - plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: _job_location
```

_job_location (the processor) returns "null" - still the  whole item / node is created.
Seems that skip_on_empty does just skip the field itself.

How to skip the whole creation of the node?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `method: process` in the plugin config will use the `process()` method in the plugin which throws a `MigrateSkipProcessException` when a field is empty and that will only skip the field.

Using `method: row` will use the `row()` method which throws a `MigrateSkipRowException` on empty field and the migration will skip the whole row.

So use `method: row` for the plugin config.

Comment: THANKS. This seems to work.